# Is this an insect (wasp/bee) bore in my soil?

Tags: soil, containers, insects, aloe

everyday there’s a new bore in the soil of my potted aloe plant. Could you help identify what this is?

There’s little mounds of soil that are balled up around the hole and I keep destroying them but they keep coming back like clockwork. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I think it is more likely to be an earthworm in your pot than a bee or wasp nesting underground, especially if the pot is indoors.

Earthworms don't "eat" plant roots, but they can cause problems by continuously disturbing the soil in the pot.

Take the plant out of the pot, have a poke around in the soil and if you find the worm, put it somewhere outside where it is meant to be living! (Ideally, put it outside at around sunset, when there are less likely to be predatory birds feeding and it will not be harmed by the UV radiation in sunlight).

Some species of bees do nest underground, but they are not solitary insects, and (from my own experience with a bumble bee nest underneath a path in my garden) you would hear them "buzzing" underground in the nest, and you would see them coming and going in the day time.